# Velocity over time from velocity over distance

Tags: kinematics

Given an equation for velocity over distance $v_x$, is it possible to derive the corresponding equation for velocity over time $v_t$? How could it be done?

For instance, consider the equation $v_x = 5x -3$, which relates the velocity of a body to its distance travelled, starting from $v_0 = 2 \frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$ at $x=0$, through $v_5 = 22 \frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$ (after the body has travelled $5$ meters).

What are the characteristics of such motion? Can $v_t$ be then derived?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by velocity over distance ? Are you referring to the velocity field in a fluid $v(x,y,z,t)$, versus the velocity of a test particle which we would put in this fluid ?

Comment: @AdrienMartina I've updated the question. What I think I'm asking is something much simpler; though, when I think about it, a fluid with different velocities across it vs the velocity (over time) of a particle placed in it seems like a perfect analogy (assuming the particle instantaneously assumes the velocity of the fluid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the relation between the instantaneous speed $v = \frac{d x(t)}{dt}$ and the position $x(t)$, this relation yields a differential equation which in your example reads
$$ \frac{dx(t)}{dt} = 5 x(t) -3 $$
with initial condition $\frac{dx}{dt}|_{t=0} = v_0$.

The general solution is
$$x(t) = \frac{3}{5} + c \ e^{5 t} $$
The initial condition fixes $c=\frac{v_0}{5}$ so that the full trajectory and its velocity are given by
$$ x(t) =\frac{3}{5} + \frac{v_0}{5} e^{5 t} $$
$$ v(t) = v_0 e^{5 t} $$

When the velocity is proportional to the distance, the trajectory is exponential in time. This is analogous to finance, where the earnings from bank interests is proportional to the account's balance, so that the balance exponentiates (theoretically) in time.

Comment: Thank you, that clears it up a lot, and I like the analogy. Btw, shouldn't the coefficient in the x(t) equation be $\frac{3}{5}$ instead of $\frac{2}{5}$? I'm going off of Wolfram Alpha here a little though, so not sure about that.

Comment: You're right. I corrected that